# Identity Server 3 and Azure AD Single Sign Out

Tags: iis, identityserver3, content-security-policy, ws-federation, x-frame-options

I'm using Identity Server 3 with WS-Federation plugin on top and Azure AD SAML2 Provider as an External Provider in Identity Server 3.

No Problems when I perform Single Sign On between IDSRV3, Client, Relying Party and AZURE AD.

The problem is when I perform Single Sign Out from Azure with authenticated RP (Ws Federation Client).

This is what I'm getting in **Firefox**:

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://localhost:5000/core/wsfed/signout does not permit cross-origin framing.

In **Chrome**:

Refused to display 'https://localhost:5000/core/wsfed/signout' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

As I see in the WsFederation plugin the "/wsfed/signout" route does not disable the XFO

```
    [Route("signout")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SignOutCallback()
    {
        Logger.Info("WS-Federation signout callback");

        var urls = await _cookies.GetValuesAndDeleteCookieAsync(WsFederationPluginOptions.CookieName);
        return new SignOutResult(urls);
    }
```

But do on the "/wsfed" GET route:

```
    [Route("")]
    [SecurityHeaders(EnableCsp = false, EnableXfo = false)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
      ...
      if (signout != null)
      {
         Logger.Info("WsFederation signout request");
         return await ProcessSignOutAsync(signout);
      }
```

Where is the mistake here? If I remove the X-Frame-Options headers in IIS directly it works fine but following the docs does not.

Any help is appreciated.